# SSDT/Visual Studio Database Project publishing DACPAC referenced DML table trigger SQL71501

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I'm unable to publish SQL DML triggers inside of a VS Database/SSDT project.  Everything else seems to publish updates/creations fine.  However, my triggers aren't ever generated in the script.  I can update/create stored procedures, table valued functions (TVFs), contracts, queues and services just fine using [dbo].[ElementName] references.

MSSQL Version: SQL Server 2014 RS2

i.e. these all work fine as their respective type (contract, service, stored procedure, etc.) and update/create based on the source/destination.

Contract:

```
CREATE CONTRACT [//Web/Queue/BasicContract]
(
    [//Web/Queue/RequestMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR,
    [//Web/Queue/ReplyMessage] SENT BY TARGET
)
```

Stored Procedure [$(SystemDb) is set as a SQLCMD variable]:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[z_Dist_Tans_Error]
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @RecordCount INT 

    SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM [$(SystemDb)].dbo.bcerr 
END;
```

However, I get a reference error with this trigger SQL code.  Error is commented in-line:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [z_Trg_MatlAvailable_Delete]
    ON [dbo].[Matlavailable] --SQL71501: Trigger: [dbo].[z_Trg_MatlAvailable_Delete] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Matlavailable]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN

END
```

I can add the SQLCMD variable into the trigger creation query.  This fixes the compile errors.  But, when publishing it doesn't seem to detect the trigger doesn't exist in the destination database so it's never created in the script.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [z_Trg_MatlAvailable_Delete]
    ON [$(SystemDb)].[dbo].[Matlavailable] --Error Resolved but never published
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN

END
```

If I add the table's SQL definition inside of my project I can resolve those reference issues and it actually publishes the triggers.  However, I'm attaching this DML trigger to our ERP system's database.  I have no control over how that database's table will evolve over time and I don't want my projects "definition" of that table to override the existing one.

It seems like I can reference DACPAC tables fine in queries but not attaching triggers (and probably more).  Is there some way to create triggers using [$(VariableName)].[Schema].[TableName] that publish with VS Database Projects *or* a way to reference DACPAC tables to create triggers using just [Schema].[TableName] ?

Comment: You can try to create separate project that would have this table definition in it. Then you need to add trigger there and add the option "Ignore tables" in publish profile. That might work, but I haven't tried. Another bad option is to deploy it via post scripts that it is baaad

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I'd considered the option of deploying via post/pre scripts but that defeats the purpose of validation since it will just execute without schema validation.  If I can make my project not drop/override existing table definitions I suppose I may be able to do that directly vs creating a different project for that.  I was hoping for a better solution but I don't think the table I'm adding triggers to changes much so that may be my only option.

Comment: if you are ok of doing that manually then I'd add this table into the project and maintain the trigger from there. You would get all the benefits of the SSDT and would still have ability of deploying manually.